# How to page break in HTML layout?

Tags: html, page-break

I would like to use **HTML layout** for print purpose. Instead of continuous print layout, I would like to split into next page. Please advice me.

Comment: Page break - like in lets say Microsoft Word?

Comment: Yes..exactly while printing.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. However, you can try

```
   <br/> for html page break.
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I am looking for page break in print purpose.